# Querying CDSE stac via python

Tags: json, request, stac, cdse

I'm trying to query Sentinel 2 data from the "new" [CDSE stac](https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/) ([docs are here](https://api.stacspec.org/v1.0.0-rc.1/item-search/#tag/Item-Search/operation/getItemSearch)). The docs seems very low level and without any working example code.

The problem I am facing is the only response returned are either Lansat-5 (I assume it actually all satellite information but limited to 1000) when the stac endpoint is https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/search/, or all Sentinel-2 data when the endpoint https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/collections/SENTINEL-2/items is used ignoring the datetime option.

Previously I used the Earth Search STAC to search for Sentinel-2 data and had no problem getting the correct information returned.

What I have noticed is that the Earth Search stac uses the `query` option whereas the CDSE stac uses the `filter` option which expects CQL2 notation. I'll admit my CQL2 knowledge/experience is very little (basically none).

Here is a very basic code snippet I used as test. just comment and uncomment the two different endpoints.

```
import requests
import json
data = {
    "bbox": [13, 45, 14, 46],
    "datetime": "2019-12-10T00:00:00Z/2019-12-10T23:59:59Z",
    "collection": ['SENTINEL-2'],
    "limit": 1,
    "filter": {"filter": "properties.collection = SENTINEL-2"},
             "filter-lang": "cql2-text"}

# url = "https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/search"
url =   "https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/collections/SENTINEL-2/items"
response = requests.get(url, json=data, verify=False).json()

print(response)
```

Has someone had success querying data in the CDSE stac, and if so, would it be possible to provide some sample request code or pointers as to how go about writing a request/query/filter body?