# Handle Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem STAC Catalog

Tags: python, stac, cdse

I'm trying to handle [CDSE](https://documentation.dataspace.copernicus.eu/APIs/STAC.html)'s STAC Catalog using my esperience with [Microsoft Planetary Computer](https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/dataset/sentinel-2-l2a#Example-Notebook).

With MPC I'm be able to download all I need but I can't do the same thing with CDSE. I've builded a simple Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pystac_client

catalog_url = "https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac"

catalog = pystac_client.Client.open(
    url=catalog_url
)

catalog
```

[image]

```
area_of_interest = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [14.335072274700622, 40.88868507222068],
            [14.335072274700622, 40.7572458523517],
            [14.524378202519358, 40.7572458523517],
            [14.524378202519358, 40.88868507222068],
            [14.335072274700622, 40.88868507222068],
        ]
    ],
}

time_of_interest = "2023-07-01/2023-07-31"

search = catalog.search(
    collections=["SENTINEL-2"],
    intersects=area_of_interest,
    datetime=time_of_interest,
    query={"eo:cloud_cover": {"lt": 10}},
)

search
```

> <pystac_client.item_search.ItemSearch at 0x7fb614b1f940>

```
items = search.item_collection()
print(f"Returned {len(items)} Items")
```

When I try to know how many items are in the search I see this error:

> APIError: {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}

Using the same code with MPC I can catch the goal:

```
import planetary_computer
import pystac_client

catalog_url = "https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac"

catalog = pystac_client.Client.open(
    "https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/api/stac/v1",
    modifier=planetary_computer.sign_inplace,
)
search = catalog.search(
    collections=["sentinel-2-l2a"],
    intersects=area_of_interest,
    datetime=time_of_interest,
    query={"eo:cloud_cover": {"lt": 10}},
)
items = search.item_collection()
print(f"Returned {len(items)} Items")
```

> Returned 7 Items

What I'm doing wrong with CDSE?

EDIT: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462896/querying-cdse-stac-via-python) a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://documentation.dataspace.copernicus.eu/APIs/STAC.html#search-for-items-by-attributes CDSE supports ONLY bbox and datetime for querying. So not with intersects and not with cloud-cover limits.. Hopefully they will improve it some day.